# Некорректное отображение графика на C#

Tags: c#, .net, графика

По заданию мне нужно создать график функции `y=(1)/(1+x^(2))`.

Программа работает исправно, однако вся загвоздка в том, что график отрисовывается не полностью, а только сама гипербола с некорректным позиционированием по Y.

Прикладываю код:

```
    private void Forml_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        one();
    }
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        one();
    }
    void one()
    {

        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics(); 
        g.Clear(Color.White); 
        Pen a = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);
        Pen b = new Pen(Color.Green, 2);
        Pen c = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
        Font signatureFont = new Font("Arial", 7);

        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat(); 
        drawFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft; 

        int sizeWidth = Form1.ActiveForm.Width; 
        int sizeHeight = Form1.ActiveForm.Height; 
        
        Point center = new Point(((int)(sizeWidth / 2) - 8), (int)((sizeHeight / 2) - 19));

        g.DrawLine(a, 10, center.Y, center.X, center.Y);
        g.DrawLine(a, center.X, center.Y, 2 * center.X - 10, center.Y); 
        g.DrawLine(a, center.X, 10, center.X, center.Y);
        g.DrawLine(a, center.X, center.Y, center.X, 2 * center.Y - 10); 
        g.DrawString("X", drawFont, drawBrush, new PointF(2 * center.X - 5, center.Y + 10), drawFormat);
        g.DrawString("Y", drawFont, drawBrush, new PointF(center.X + 30, 5), drawFormat);
        g.DrawLine(a, center.X, 10, center.X + 5, 20);
        g.DrawLine(a, center.X, 10, center.X - 5, 20);


        int stepForAxes = 25;
        int lenghtShtrih = 3;
        int maxValueForAxesX = 4;
        int maxValueForAxesY = 9;

        float oneDelenieX = (float)maxValueForAxesX / ((float)center.X / (float)stepForAxes);
        float oneDelenieY = (float)maxValueForAxesY / ((float)center.Y / (float)stepForAxes);



        for (int i = center.X, j = center.X, k = 1; i < 2 * center.X - 30; j -= stepForAxes, i += stepForAxes, k++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(a, i, center.Y - lenghtShtrih, i, center.Y + lenghtShtrih);
            g.DrawLine(a, j, center.Y - lenghtShtrih, j, center.Y + lenghtShtrih);


            if (i < 2 * center.X - 55)
            {
                g.DrawString((k * oneDelenieX).ToString("0.0"), signatureFont, drawBrush, new PointF(i + stepForAxes + 9, center.Y + 6), drawFormat);
                g.DrawString(((k * oneDelenieX).ToString("0.0").ToString() + "-"), signatureFont, drawBrush, new PointF(j - stepForAxes + 9, center.Y + 6), drawFormat);
            }
        }
        for (float i = center.Y, j = center.Y, k = 1; i < 2 * center.Y - 30; j -= stepForAxes, i += stepForAxes, k++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(a, center.X - lenghtShtrih, i, center.X + lenghtShtrih, i);
            g.DrawLine(a, center.X - lenghtShtrih, j, center.X + lenghtShtrih, j); ;

            if (i < 2 * center.Y - 55)
            {
                g.DrawString(((k * oneDelenieX).ToString("0.0").ToString() + "-"), signatureFont, drawBrush, new PointF(center.X + 25, i + stepForAxes + 9), drawFormat);
                g.DrawString((k * oneDelenieX).ToString("0.0"), signatureFont, drawBrush, new PointF(center.X + 25, j - stepForAxes + 9), drawFormat);
            }
        }

            g.DrawLine(a, center.X * 2 - 10, center.Y, center.X * 2 - 20, center.Y + 5);
            g.DrawLine(a, center.X * 2 - 10, center.Y, center.X * 2 - 20, center.Y - 5);

        int numOfPoint = 100;

                float[] first = new float[numOfPoint];

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoint; i++)
                {
                    first[i] = (float)maxValueForAxesX / (float)numOfPoint * (i + 1) - (float)(maxValueForAxesX / 2);
                }

                float[] second = new float[numOfPoint];

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoint; i++)
                {
                     second[i] = 1 / 1 + (float)(first[i] * (float)first[i]);
                }
                Point[] pointOne = new Point[numOfPoint];

                float tempX = 1 / oneDelenieX * stepForAxes;
                float tempY = 1 / oneDelenieY * stepForAxes;
                
                for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoint; i++)
                {
                    
                    pointOne[i].X = center.X + (int)(first[i] * tempX);
                    pointOne[i].Y = center.Y + (int)(second[i] * tempY);
                    
                }

                g.DrawLines(b, pointOne);
                g.DrawCurve(b, pointOne);
                g.DrawBeziers(b, pointOne);
        
    }
}
```

Подозреваю, что ошибка находится в функции second[i], но я искренне не понимаю как ее изменить.

Заранее благодарю за все предложенные варианты!

Answer (score 3):

Кхм, собственно сам решил свой вопрос, если у кого-то будет аналогичная ситуация, обратите внимание на правильность поставленных скобок.

```
second[i] = (1) / (1 + ((float)(first[i]) * (float)(first[i])));
```

Отредактировав формулу она стала работать корректно.